# What happens after SEC revokes the registration of a stock?

Tags: united-states, stocks, regulation, sec, delisting

Looking at **United Development FUnding Income Fund IV** (which was a listed REIT on Nasdaq which subsequently traded OTC):

- This security had its registration revoked by SEC on 2020.08.13,
  according to last page of
  https://www.sec.gov/litigation/opinions/2020/34-89535.pdf
- However, on 2021.09.23, UDF says
  *United Development Funding IV (“UDF IV”) announced today that on August 9, 2021 its board of trustees authorized a cash distribution
  of $0.065 per share* (Link http://www.udfonline.com/united-development-funding-iv-and-united-development-funding-income-fund-v-announce-distributions-aug12/)

Q1 -  What happens after a security registration is revoked by SEC? (I was surprised that, there can be cash distributions for a security which has its registration revoked.)

Q2 - Separately: SEC [says](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersdfnctcohtm.html) *Broker-dealers may not execute any trades in stocks whose registration has been revoked pursuant to Section 12(j).* I guess this means existing shareholders can still trade with counterparties other than broker-dealers?)

Comment: Related SEC webpage: [Defunct Company, Stock Continues to Trade](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersdfnctcohtm.html)

Comment: "I was surprised that, there can be cash distributions for a security which has its registration revoked" — When a company's stock has its registration revoked, the company effectively becomes a private company. Private companies can also pay dividends.

Comment: @Flux Please answer questions in an answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica That does not answer the question. It is a comment on the OP's side note.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Based on this [article](https://www.securitieslawyer101.com/2021/the-sec-just-suspended-my-stock-now-what/) "Once registration has been revoked, the stock’s ticker will be deleted.  Shareholders will still be shareholders but in a private company.  Their stock will be extremely illiquid, and its value will be difficult to determine, as there is no public market for it."

Q2. Correct, broker-dealers may not execute any trades resulting in the stock to be very illiquid and the chances that broker-dealers execute stocks of those kinds are 50/50 chance.

There are changes though taking effect on the OTC markets coming September 28th. More information [here](https://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2020-212)